Font weight in header is last weight in import list (regardless of specification)
Regardless of what font weight I specify in the header, it does not change, the only way to change it is to change the last weight in the import list. (And even this does not work if I add a weight between 600 and 900, e.g. 700.)
However the font weight in the scroll boxes changes fine.
I have no coding experience and this is baffling behavior. How can I make the font weight in the header actually work? (It does show up in Inspect Element and font size works)
    /* Import Libre Franklin font from Google Fonts */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Franklin:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;900&display=swap');

body {
    font-family: 'Libre Franklin';
    background-color: #fef5df; /* Taupe color */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.site-header {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 9px 0 0px;
    background-color: ; /* White background for header */
    font-size: 15pt; /* 30pt font size */
    font-weight: 500; /* Bold font */
    color: #000; /* Black font color */
}

.box-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: 20px; /* Adjust margin between header and boxes */
    margin-left: 90px; /* Fixed margin on the left side */
    margin-right: 90px; /* Fixed margin on the right side */
}

.large-box {
    flex: 1 1 50%; /* Flex-grow, flex-shrink, and initial flex-basis */
    height: 500px; /* Height of the large box */
    background-color: #ad8a32;
    font-size: 12pt; /* 30pt font size */
}

.small-box {
    flex: 1 1 40%; /* Flex-grow, flex-shrink, and initial flex-basis */
    height: 500px; /* Height of the small box */
}

.scrolling-box {
    margin: 10px; /* Adjust margin around each box */
    padding: 15px; /* Adjust padding inside each box */
    background-color: #ffffff; /* White background for scrolling boxes */
    border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Light gray border */
    overflow-y: auto; /* Enable vertical scrollbar if needed */
    font-weight: 400; /* Bold font */
}


If you import all the weights, all the weights will work.


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Franklin:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

body {
  font-family: 'Libre Franklin';
  background-color: #fef5df;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 9px 0 0px;
  font-size: 30pt;
}

.a {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.b {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.c {
  font-weight: 700; /* bold */
}

.d {
  font-weight: 800;
}

.e {
  font-weight: 900;
}
<h1 class="a">500</h1>
<h1 class="b">600</h1>
<h1 class="c">700</h1>
<h1 class="d">800</h1>
<h1 class="e">900</h1>



If you want help with your code specifically, you need to edit your post to include a stack snippet which demonstrates the problem.
